# How to convert bits into bytes in python?

Tags: python

I'm using the following code to turn characters into bits and I don't know how to convert the bits back into their characters.

I tried following the steps I took to reverse the process. I know that the opposite of ord() is chr(), but how do I reverse the format(ord(char),"b")?
any help is appreciated

```
temp = format(ord(char), 'b')
```

Comment: Are you asking to turn characters into the bit representation of their code points? That's awesome, but consider changing the title. Generally speaking, `ord` and `chr` should not be used for converting between characters and bytes, you should use character encodings. (Not trying to be mean or anything: I'm just pointing that out for people that land here: `ord` and `chr` are fine _only_ when you are writing scripts that specifically deal with code points! They should not be used for general encoding and decoding tasks. Code point work is cool though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the string back to an integer with `int()` passing a base of `2` and then back to a character with `chr()`:

```
temp = format(ord('a'), 'b')
print(temp)
#'1100001'

c = chr(int(temp, 2))
print(c)
# 'a'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I've been looking for

Answer (score 2):

Mark Meyer's answer is spot on, and works for any *character*:

```
>>> char = ''
>>> bits = format(ord(char), 'b')
>>> bits
'11111011000001110'
>>> char = chr(int(bits, 2))
>>> char
''
```

But it only works for characters, not for grapheme clusters. Suppose you had the woman scientist emoji:

```
>>> char = '‍'
>>> bits = format(ord(char), 'b')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

This does not work because the woman scientist emoji is not a single character, but rather a grapheme cluster made up of three characters:

- WOMAN
- ZERO WIDTH JOINER
- MICROSCOPE

So the string has three characters and you can not do `ord` on a three character string.

I think it's important to not here that turning a single character into a bit string for its code point is highly unusual and in practice this is never really done (unless you are using an encoding known as UTF-32 BE, in which case you should pad the bit string out with zeros to 32 places). IMHO, what you *should* be doing here is NOT using `ord` and `chr`, but rather encoding and decoding using UTF-8. The very idea of turning characters into bits or bytes should be done with a well known character encoding scheme, and UTF-8 is the most proper.

Here is how I would suggest you do the character and bit thing:

```
>>> char = '‍'
>>> bytes = char.encode('utf-8')
>>> bytes
b'\xf0\x9f\x91\xa9\xe2\x80\x8d\xf0\x9f\x94\xac'
>>> char = bytes.decode('utf-8')
>>> char
'‍'
```

If you want bits and not bytes, then:

```
>>> char = '‍'
>>> bytes = char.encode('utf-8')
>>> bits = ''.join(f'{b:08b}' for b in bytes)
>>> bits
'1111000010011111100100011010100111100010100000001000110111110000100111111001010010101100'
```

Comment: That's a great explanation Ray.

Answer (score 0):

To and from bits using Python 3.6+ f-strings:

```
>>> char = 'a'
>>> bits = f'{ord(char):08b}'  # 08b means 8 binary digits with leading zeros.
>>> bits
'01100001'
>>> chr(int(bits,2)) # convert string to integer using base 2.
'a'
```